# How to calculate the (smallest) distance between a set of lines and a point?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, distance

So basically I am trying to label if some GPS points are very close to a road.

I have vectors of lat-lon coordinates which, when connected to the the subsequent/antecedent row in the vector, form a line which represents a road (depicted as matplotlib plots in colors)
I also have simple geographic points (lat-lon) (depicted as matplotlib scatter plot in black)
[image: two muppets]

i would like to label whether a point is near a road (e.g. within 0.001 radians distance) - for that, I am guessing one would need to calculate the closest distance of a point to this set of vectors.

```py
#example vector 1
[[-84.3146272, 33.7741084], [-84.3145183, 33.7741196]]
#example vector 2
[[-84.4043106, 33.7700542], [-84.4045421, 33.770055]]

#example point to predict wether it will be near one of these two lines
[-84.31106, 33.73887]
```

How can one tackle this problem? I cannot think of a way to solve this, but when looking at the plot it seems simple... Is there a library that could help?

Comment: check sicpy cdist or nnumpy.linalg.norm

Comment: You have decimal degree coordinates.  0.001 radians can't be translated to a planar distance except over very small latitudinal differences since longitude spacing decreases as one moves poleward.  You will get close-ish if your northern and southern latitudes are close

Comment: I updated my post, and added an Euclidean approximation to the algorithm, which may work faster and provide a comparable result. Take your pick which method you would prefer. I haven't tested the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are working with the spherical model of the Earth. Then I suppose what you call "lines" are in fact arc-segments of great circles (the straight lines of spherical geometry). In other words, you have one point `p1` on the surface of the sphere with lat-lon coordinates `[lat1, lon1]` and another point `p2` on the sphere with lat-lon coordinates `[lat2, lon2]`. What is considered "the straight line" on the sphere that passes through `p1` and `p2` is the unique circle (called great circle) obtained by the intersection of the sphere with the plane that passes through the center of the sphere and the two points `p1` and `p2`. Then, what you call a "line", is the smaller of the two circular arcs from this great circle, bounded by the two points `p1` and `p2`.

The distance you would like to calculate (in radians) could be the distance from a third point `p` with lat-lon coordinates `[lat, lon]` to the arc-segment determined by the two points `p1` and `p2`. The said distance should be the arc-length of the arc from the great circle passing through `p` and perpendicular to the great circle of `p1` and `p2`. This perpendicular great circle is the one determined by the intersection of the sphere with the plane perpendicular to the plane of the great circle of `p1` and `p2` and passing through the point  `p` and the center of the sphere. If the intersection of the perpendicular great circle with the great-circle arc `p1 p2` is a point `h` inside the arc-segment `p1 p2`, then the length of the great circle arc `p h` is the sought distance. If, however, `h` is outside the arc `p1 p2` the the sought distance is either `p p1` or `p p2` whichever is smaller.

Here is some Matlab code that calculates the shortest distance between a point and an arc-interval:

```matlab
lat_lon = [lat, lon];
lat_lon1 = [lat1, lon1];
lat_lon2 = [lat2, lon2];

function dist = dist_point_2_road(lat_lon, lat_lon1, lat_lon2)

   % you may have to convert lat-long angles from degrees to radians 

   % First, convert from lat-long coordinates to 3D coordinates of points on the unit    
   % sphere. Since Earth's radius cancels out in our computations, we simply assume it 
   % is R = 1 
   lat = lat_lon(1);
   lon = lat_lon(2);

   lat1 = lat_lon1(1);
   lon1 = lat_lon1(2);

   lat2 = lat_lon2(1);
   lon2 = lat_lon2(2);

   p1 = [ cosd(lat1)*cosd(lon1),  cosd(lat1)*sind(lon1),  sind(lat1) ]; %cosd = cos(degrees)
   p2 = [ cosd(lat2)*cosd(lon2),  cosd(lat2)*sind(lon2),  sind(lat2) ]; %sind = sin(degrees)
   p = [ cosd(lat)*cosd(lon),  cosd(lat)*sind(lon),  sind(lat) ];

   % n12 is the unit vector perpendicular to the plane of the great circle 
   % determined by the points p1 and p2  
   n12 = cross(p1, p2);
   n12 = n12 / sqrt(dot(n12, n12));
   sin_of_dist = dot(p, n12); % sine of the angle that equals arc-distance 
                              % from point p to the great arc p1 p2  

   dist = pi/2 - acos(abs(sin_of_dist)); % acos = arccos, abs() = absolute value
          % dist is the shortest distance in radians from p to the 
          % great circle determined by the points p1 and p2

   n1 = cross(p1, p); 
   n1 = n1 / sqrt(dot(n1, n1));
   % unit normal vector perpendicular to the great-arc determined by p and p1

   n2 = cross(p, p2);
   n2 = n1 / sqrt(dot(n2, n2));
   % unit normal vector perpendicular to the great-arc determined by p and p2

   if dot(n12, n1) < 0 % if the angle of spherical triangle p p1 p2 at vertex p1 is obtuse 
      dist = acos(dot(p, p1)); % the shortest distance is p p1 
   elseif dot(n12, n2) < 0 % if the angle of spherical triangle p p1 p2 at vertex p2 is obtuse 
      dist = acos(dot(p, p2)); % the shortest distance is p p2 
   end

   % the function returns the appropriate dist as output 

end
```

You can iterate this for the sequence of arc-intervals that form a road and select the smallest distance to an arc-interval.

According to this computation, the distance of the point to the first "vector 1" is
`0.0000615970599633145` radians and the distance to the second "vector 2" is
`0.00162840939265068` radians. The point is closest to a point inside vector 1, but for vector 2, it is closest to to one of the ends of the arc-interval.

**Edit.** Now, if one wants to use Euculdiean (flat) approximation, ignoring Earths curvature, one may needs to convert lat-lon coordinates into Euclidean flat approximation coordinates. To avoid any map specific coordinates, one may be tempted to plot latitude against longitude coordinates. That may be ok around the equator, but the closer to the poles one gets, the more innaccurate these coordinates gets at representing distance data. This is because closer to the poles, distance along a fixed latitude is much shorter than distance along a fixed longitude. That is why we need to correct this discrepancy. This is done by using the Riemannian metric on the sphere in lat-long coordinates, or simply by looking at the 3D geometry of latitude and longitude circles near a given point on the sphere.

```matlab
lat_lon = [lat, lon];
lat_lon1 = [lat1, lon1];
lat_lon2 = [lat2, lon2];

%center of approximate Euclidean coordinate system is point p 
% with lat_long coordinates and the scaling coefficient of longitude, 
% which equalizes longitude and latitude distance at point p, is

a = cosd(lat_long(1));  

function  x = convert_2_Eucl(lat_long1, lat_long, a)
   x = [lat_long1(1) - lat_long(1),  a*(lat_long1(2) - lat_long(2))];
end

% convert from lat-long to approximate Euclidean coordinates
x1 = convert_2_Eucl(lat_long1, lat_long, a);
x2 = convert_2_Eucl(lat_long2, lat_long, a);

function dist = dist_point_2_road(x1, x2)

   dist = dot(x1, x1) * dot(x2 - x1, x2 - x1) - dot(x1, x2 - x1)^2 ;
   dist = sqrt( dist / ( dot(x2 - x1, x2 - x1)^2) );
   % dist is the distance from the point p, which has Eucl coordinates [0,0] 
   % to the straight Euclidean interval x1 x2 representing the interval p1 p2

   if dot(x1, x2 - x1) > 0
      dist = sqrt( dot(x1, x1) );
   elseif dot(x2, x1 - x2) > 0
      dist = sqrt( dot(x2, x2) );
   end

end
```

**Remark:** the latter function calculates distance, but it might be equally convenient to just calculate `dist^2`, avoiding the calculation of the square root `sqrt` in order to speed up the performance. Measuring with respect to dist^2 should work just as well.

You choose which function you want, the spherical one or approximately Euclidean. The latter is probably faster. You can choose to remove the square root and calculate distance squared to make things even faster.

I wrote this in a hurry, so there might be some inaccuracies.

Comment: hmm.. while some roads may lead all the way to rome, in this case they are short and local enough to ignore the curvature of the earth for the purpose of determining which road is a point closest to.

Comment: @user2297550 Yes, I know that, but your data is in spherical coordinates. To use Eculidean flat approximation, you need to convert it. And on top of that straight lines on your map are map dependant and if the map changes, what was once a straight line, is not straihgt anymore.What I wrote is map indepepndent. Do you have a converter of spherical coordinates to Euclidean? You cannot just plot longitude against latitude, because in the Nordic countries and Alaska longitude changes much faster than latitude.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not the asker; just a passerby, but your clarification will help everybody.

Comment: @2297550 Sorry, now I noticed the difference. I actually added an Euclidean approximation, which may be faster. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's nice of you. Keep adding awesome answers :-)